# How to change result of laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have an one to one relationship in laravel same as following:

```
public function Category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class);
}
```

and run this eloquent query:

```
Product::with('category')->first();
```

this query return:

```
{
    "name": "Green Book",
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Book"
    }
}
```

but I went this data:

```
{
    "name": "Green Book",
    "category": "Book"
}
```

Is it possible to do this without using a loop?

Comment: You can try `Product::with('category:name')->first();`. It might fail because it needs the id to make the relation or it might work, but still to be an array with the name. In that case you can map over the data. If you give more context to your question maybe a better solution could be provided.

Comment: `Categories::class` shouldn't be plural. There's something wrong in the relationship method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it seems like you have a 1-X relationship which you are mistakenly using as a many to one. Your `belongsTo` should be `hasOne` since the your items have one category not the other way around.

You can use the `$appends` property to append a custom field and make it behave as though it's part of your model:

Rename your relationship and add a mutator and accessor:

```php
public function categoryRelationship()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Categories::class);
}

public function getCategoryAttribute() {
    return $this->categoryRelationship->name;
}

public function setCategoryAttribute($value) {
   $this->categoryRelationship->name = $value;
}
```

You can also choose to add an event to automatically save your relationship when the model is being saved to ensure it works transparently:

```php
protected static function booted()
    {
        static::saving(function ($myModel) {
            $myModel->categoryRelationship->save();
        });
    }
}
```

Finally you add the `$appends` property to ensure your new attribute is alwasy included in the model as though it's a native one.

```php
protected $appends = [ 'category' ];

// This is so you don't end up also showing the relationship
protected $hidden = [ 'categoryRelationship' ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I get same result
so, i tried but didn't get right result.
how to change the result of laravel eloquent relation.
I found one way and used transformer.
we can change the result in transformer.

```
 $result = Event::with(['eventType'])
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->first();
    return $this->trans->transform($result);
```

this is the result and i used transformer as follow.

```
 public function transform(Event $Event)
{
    return [
        'id' => $Event->id,
        'company_id' => $Event->company_id,
        'calendar_id' => $Event->calendar_id,
        'case_id' => $Event->case_id,
        'user_id' => $Event->user_id,
        'title' => $Event->title,
        'description' => $Event->description,
        'duration' => $Event->duration,
        'alert_at' => $Event->alert_at,
        'alert_email' => $Event->alert_email,
        'email_sent' => $Event->email_sent,
        'alert_popup' => $Event->alert_popup,
        'popup_triggered' => $Event->popup_triggered,
        'created_by' => $Event->created_by,
        'completed' => $Event->completed,
        'alert_offset' => $Event->alert_offset,
        'icon' => $Event->icon,
        'color' => $Event->color,
        'snoozed' => $Event->snoozed,
        'type_id' => $Event->type_id,
        'datetime' => $Event->at,
        'endtime' => $Event->end_time,
        'event_type_name'=>$Event->eventType->name,
    ];
}
```

then, we can get right result. Focuse on `'event_type_name'=>$Event->eventType->name,`
But i have one problem yet.
now, the result is only 1 row. it is just `first()`.
but if i use `get()`, i can't use transformer.
of course, i can loop the result using `foreach()`.
but i think it is not right way.
what is better way?
Please answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel Doc **Eager Loading Specific Columns**

You may use the following

```
Product::with('category:id,name')->first();
```

Or you may do it yourself :

```
$product = Product::with('category')->first();
$product->category = $product->category->name;
```

Comment: You need to include `id` when eager loading specific columns: `Product::with('category:id,name')->first();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `leftJoin`

```php
return \App\Product::leftJoin('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
->select('products.*', 'categories.title as category')->get();
```